# How do you get to the root cause of a sleep interruption in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep, interrupted-exception

I've got some code:

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Some code

        Thread.sleep();

        // Some more code.
    }
}

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
List<MyTask> tasks = getTasks();
for(MyTask t : tasks)
    executor.execute(t);

executor.shutdownNow()
if(!executor.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
    TimeoutException toExc = new TimeoutException("MyAPp hung after the 30 minutes timeout was reached.")   // TODO
    log.error(toExc)

    throw toExc
}
```

When I run this with multiple `MyTask` instances coming back from `getTasks()`, I'm getting very mysterious:

```
[pool-3-thread-3] INFO me.myapp.MyTask - java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    ...etc.
```

The problem here is that there's no root cause: the thread sleeps are just "interrupted" at some point.

So I ask: **when/why is a `Thread.sleep()` interrupted, and what could I do to get to the root cause of the exception?**

Comment: Do you cancel the `Future`? Do you stop the thread pool?

Comment: Sorry please see updated code. Not sure what you mean by "canceling the Future" (?). My *undertsanding* of `Executor#execute()` is that it simply runs the `Runnable`.

Comment: You use `shutdownNow` - That's why. " This implementation cancels tasks via Thread.interrupt(), " You should be using `shutdown`. See [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown())

Comment: Thanks @Fildor (+1) - but should I use `shutdown` or `shutdownAndAwaitTermination`? (And why)?

Comment: shutdownAndAwaitTermination is a (good) example for what you want to do. As far as I remember it is not a member function, though ... By the way: The Javadocs are extremely good for these classes. I recommend reading them carefully.

Comment: It’s actually two methods: [`shutdown()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) followed by [`awaitTermination( … )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread a task is executing on can be interrupted by issuing

```
future.cancel(true);
```

against the Future object returned from the call to `executorService.submit(runnable);`

If you are getting many such exceptions, another possibility is that the whole executor service was shut down using

```
executorService.shutdownNow();
```

There is no direct way to find out which action by which thread actually turned the `interrupted` flag on.

Comment: Thanks @William F. Jameson (+1) - I am in fact using `executorService.shutdownNow()` (please see my updates). So I guess my question is: how do I gracefully wait for all runnables to finish executing before shutting down the executor service?

Comment: See my comment @IAmYourFaja

Comment: There's actually a quite simple answer to that: just go to the `ExecutorService` Javadoc page and study the provided example code for `shutdownAndAwaitTermination`.

Answer (score 1):

As a bit of a hack you could, instead of implementing `Runnable` extend `Thread`. You could then override `interrupt` and grab a stack trace before forwarding the call.

I would not recommend this for final code but when tracking down strange interrupts this may be the only way.

```
public class InterruptAwareThread extends Thread {
    volatile String interruptedStack = null;
    @Override
    public void interrupt () {
        StringWriter s = new StringWriter();
        new Exception().printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(s));
        interruptedStack = s.toString();
        super.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Referencing to the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) for `Thread.sleep()`, another Thread has interrupted yours.

> **Throws:**
>   InterruptedException - if any thread has interrupted the current thread. The interrupted status of the current thread is cleared when this exception is thrown.

The [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) for `InterruptedException` shows more details:

> Thrown when a thread is waiting, sleeping, or otherwise occupied, and the thread is interrupted, either before or during the activity. Occasionally a method may wish to test whether the current thread has been interrupted, and if so, to immediately throw this exception.